# How to store a percentage value if I'm using the NumberFormat in Java

Tags: java, string, format, numbers, integer

I'm trying to code a variable that will generate a random number between 0-6 so it can provide me with a percentage (0, 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 50% or 60%) and I'm having an issue with storing the percentage in a variable (not sure if it's an int or a double, etc.). When I print it out as

```
System.out.print("\n " + fmt1.format(randomNum));
```

it works, however I want to store it in a variable (`perc`) so I can use it later. What format (`int`, `double`, etc.) do I need so I can store a percentage in it? I get the error:

```java
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int.
```

I also have to use the Number Format so please help me out based on that not multiply by 100.

```java
randomNum = gen.nextInt(7);  
perc = fmt1.format(randomNum);
System.out.print("\n " + perc);
```

Comment: Some context is missing from the question, but it sounds like there needs to be two variables: 1) a double that can be used for calculations; 2) a String that has the double nicely formatted for display.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to store the numbers with the % sign because if you do not you could store them as ints (10,20,30,40,50,60) then add on the % sign later.  If you do need to store them as a percent then you could store them as a float (.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6) if you need to math operations with the percent.

Comment: I need the % sign on all the numbers, the only problem is I need to multiply those percentages, so I need the type of variable to multiply too

Comment: You could create a class to store the data in all of the ways you need to them or store it as a string but then you can not do math with the numbers. There is no primitive way to store an int and a %.